# Find transfer function \$V_o(V_i)\$ on a figure

Tags: circuit-analysis, digital-logic, transfer-function

Given this figure:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEnG4q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I want to calculate the transfer function of \$V_o(V_i)\$, but I can't find any good resource on it and I thought someone could explain to me how it's done, also with those NANDs I wanted to create inverters.

Comment: To me a "transfer function" suggests a linear system and this isn't a linear system. What are you trying to do?

Comment: To represent under an analytic form the ecuations of the transfer function \$V_o(V_i)\$ for this circuit...

Comment: Are you sure that your circuit is correct? Shouldn't R2 be connected after C2 at the input of a gate 2? And are you looking for a "transfer function" of a logic circuit? At the input, you have a delay circuit and an "edge detection" circuit to shorter the inputs time.

Comment: See [Transfer function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_function). I don't think you can do it because the circuit is mixed analog and digital. Is this homework?

Comment: @G36 Yeah sorry, There should be one more resistor after the C2 with the same value, sorry. I edited it,,,

Comment: @Transistor It's some kind of homework yeah, but I have no idea how to do it, and can't find any material to do this on a mixed as you said analog and digital...

Comment: The NANDs are digital logic, and therefore you need to know the input voltage threshold (the input voltage at which the NANDs switch their output).

Comment: @StefanWyss 50% of the input voltage, no?

Comment: Why do you think it's 50%? It could also be like 30%.

Comment: @StefanWyss Just assume a value, it's more important on how the exercise should be solved than this....

Comment: Ok, then you need to find the transfer function of V1/R1/C1 first and calculate how long it takes until the input of the first NAND reaches 50%.